# Vlsi multi cycle path

Tags: signal, vlsi

In multi cycle path of 3 cycles, the setup for data D1 is checked at 3rd cycle. But for the next data, D2, the setup will be checked at 4th cycle or 6th cycle?

I have this doubt because, data takes 3 cycles to propagate, so that means after 1st launch the data will reach by 3rd edge and similarly data launched at 2nd edge will reach by 4th edge.

I am thinking like... data propagation as car travelling in a road. At a time two cars can be at two different positions in the same road(net).

Comment: The thing is you never launch data at second edge on such a multipath ....

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that isn't how static timing analysis works. It isn't a simulator.

Second, that isn't how multi-cycle paths work. If it takes 3 cycles for the data to propagate, you can't launch new data every cycle. You'd need to have pipeline registers for that to work, and that would eliminate the multi-cycle path — each stage of the pipeline would be single-cycle.

Comment: Thank you Dave, and that is exactly why I always say that you should avoid using multi-cycle paths until you really, really understand them. There are just too many pitfalls.